# Instascrape (InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: 'url' must be a string" )

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

> Error: InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: 'url' must be a string

I'm trying to scrape a specific instagram profile for the upload date, comments, and likes data using [Instascrape](https://github.com/chris-greening/instascrape) on Mac. My code is based on trying to reproduce Chris Greening's [Visualizing Instagram Engagement](https://dev.to/chrisgreening/visualizing-instagram-engagement-with-instascrape-326h) code, but for the profile I am looking to retrieve data from. I had been having issues entering my executable path in Selenium, so I imported [ChromeDriveManager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) to solve this.

My issue, at least from what I can understand, is that the DataFrame is not receiving the data? There had been instance in which my scrape ran 'successfully' but still yielded an empty DataFrame. Please let me know what you might think, or if any additional information would be necessary for me to provide. My most recent code is below.

```py
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from instascrape import Profile, scrape_posts
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
#defining path for Google Chrome webdriver;
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())


# Scraping profile
SESSIONID = 'session id'   #Actual session id excluded on purpose
headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edg/87.0.664.57",
            "cookie": f"sessionid={SESSIONID};"}
prof = Profile('https://www.instagram.com/username/') #username exlcuded as well
prof.scrape()

# Scraping the posts
posts = prof.get_posts(webdriver=driver, login_first=True)
scraped, unscraped = scrape_posts(posts, silent=False, headers=headers, pause=10)

posts_data = [post.to_dict() for post in posts]
posts_df = pd.DataFrame(posts_data)
print(posts_df[['upload_date', 'comments', 'likes']])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing too much relevant information, so I cant see what method and what code line causes the problem, but it's quite clear that you trying to use some "url", probably with a kind of `driver.get(url)` while you providing invalid data there, probably `None` type.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question that I've posted on StackOverflow. What else would be useful to provide?

Comment: Here is more info on the error, maybe this helps? 
'code' 

File "/Users/andrew7/.spyder-py3/autosave/code for stackover .py", line 32, in <module>
    print(posts_df[['upload_date', 'comments', 'likes']])
File "/Users/andrew7/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2908, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True)[1]
Which give me: 
 'KeyError: "None of [Index(['upload_date', 'comments', 'likes'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"'

Comment: When I run: print(posts_df) 
I get: 
print(posts_df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []